# SonataAdminBundle - How to change route to dashboard?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have installed Symfony 2.2.0 with SonataAdminBundle. Now I'd like to change default dashboard route from `/dashboard` to `/`.

How to do it in a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

- Create a copy of the sonata route file
  https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml
- and make necessary changes.  Save the file in one of your bundles
- In your app/config/routing.yml refer to this route file

> ```
> admin:
>    resource: '@AcmeAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
>    prefix: /admin
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use as below into your **app/config/routing.yml** file:

```
default:
    pattern:  /admin/
    defaults: { _controller: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard }
```